# Process builder update other child records except himself

Tags: process-builder, master-detail

I have a process builder, which is triggered by a child object, `Asset`. As an action I want it to update other child records for the same parent `Account`. But it should update all related `Asset` records except the one which triggers the process. The relationship itself works but not the 2nd filter condition. It always updates all child records. It appears that the process builder in the filter condition as field reference uses values not from the record which triggered the process but from the one which is considered by the filter. Therefore it always updates all.
Debug log doesn't show which ID is used in the filter condition.

*Note: Farm ID is Asset ID, we renamed Assets to Farms*

[image]

Any idea how to filter the record which triggered the process from the update action?

Comment: did you look at this [Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232312&language=en_US&type=1)?

Comment: @cropredy yes. But as you can see I tried a similar thing, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try three decision branches, all with same entry condition; Branch 1- set asset field IsProtected = true, Branch 2 - apply sibling update except to Asset where IsProtected=true; Branch 3 - set IsProtected = false

Comment: I don't see field IsProtected on the asset object.

Comment: Custom field I meant - Is_Protected__c. Or any name you find useful